# What happens when a panic roll is made while using a melee weapon?

Tags: melee-combat, alien-rpg

Triggering a Panic Roll (rolling a 1 on a Stress die) while using a ranged weapon causes the character to empty their magazine, firing wildly, and requiring a reload of precious ammunition to continue using the weapon.

Is there a similar mechanic when using melee weapons, causing them to lose effectiveness when a Stress die comes up as a 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. This is simply a way to determine when your current magazine runs out so the mechanic only exist for ranged weapons.

If you don't want to lose an action reloading next round you could switch to using your rifle as a close combat weapon. It would then count as a "blunt instrument" from the Close combat weapons table.